# GOOGLE Analytics API taking time for next request

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get the data from Google analytics Reporting API, the problem is that the first request quickly gets the data but the next request is taking around 5 mins.Does it happen because of my pagination code which is happening in while loop?

My Page Size is "300". I used this size to check my pagination.

```
        from apiclient.discovery import build
        from time import sleep
        from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
        import pandas as pd

        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'analytcisproject.json'
        VIEW_ID = '182363141'

        #dd = [] 
        #for pag_index in range(0, 50): 
        #    dd.append(service.data().ga().get( ids='ga:', start_date='2018-04-01', end_date='2018-04-30', dimensions = "ga:date,ga:dimension2", metrics='ga:pageviews', start_index=str(pag_index*10000+1), max_results=str(pag_index*10000+10000)).execute()) 

        #print(dd)    


        def initialize_analyticsreporting():
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
            analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
            return analytics

        def get_report(analytics, pageTokenVariable):
            return analytics.reports().batchGet(
              body={
                'reportRequests': [
                {
                  'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                  'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '50daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
                  'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},{'expression': 'ga:users'},{'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}
                              ,{'expression': 'ga:sessionDuration'},{'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'},{'expression': 'ga:pageLoadTime'},{'expression': 'ga:bounceRate'}],
                  'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},{'name': 'ga:browser'},
                                 {'name':'ga:city'},{'name':'ga:country'},{'name':'ga:medium'},
                                 {'name':'ga:continent'},{'name':'ga:landingScreenName'},{'name':'ga:pagePath'}
                                 ,{'name':'ga:userType'}],
                    "pageToken": pageTokenVariable,

                     "pageSize": "300",


                }]
              }
          ).execute()



        analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
        response = get_report(analytics, "0")

        for report in response.get('reports', []):
            j=0
            list = []
            pagetoken = report.get('nextPageToken', None)
            print(pagetoken)
            #------printing the pagetoken here returns `100,000` which is expected

            for report in response.get('reports', []):
                columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
                dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
                metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
                rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
                for row in rows:
                    dict = {}
                    dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
                    dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])
                    for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
                        dict[header] = dimension
                    for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
                        for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                            if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                                dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                            else:
                                dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)
                    list.append(dict)
                    j=j+1
                    print(j)
                    #print(response)
              # Append that data to a list as a dictionary

        # pagination function
            while   pagetoken != "" and pagetoken != None:  # This says while there is info in the nextPageToken get the data, process it and add to the list
                i=0
                response = get_report(analytics, pagetoken)
                #pagetoken = response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken']
                pagetoken = response['reports'][0].get('nextPageToken') 
                print(pagetoken)
                #------printing the pagetoken here returns `200,000` as is expected but the data being pulled is the same as for the first batch and so on. While in the loop the pagetoken is being incremented but it does not retrieve new data
                for row in rows:
                    dict = {}
                    dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
                    dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])
                    for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
                        dict[header] = dimension
                    for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
                        for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                            if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                                dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                            else:
                                dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)
                    list.append(dict)
                    sleep(1)
                    i=i+1
                    print(i)

                    #df = pd.DataFrame(list)
                    if i==3:
                       break;

            print('afn')


        df = pd.DataFrame(list)
        #df.head()
        #response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm not a python expert.
  You have a "sleep(1)" in your row loop, so 1 second for each row = 300 seconds per row (5 mins). that would make the most sense to me.

Try removing the sleep in your row loop.

I hope that helps.